# Bing API: How to get data types for requested report columns?

Tags: bing-api, bing-ads-api

What is the best way to get data type when pulling performance data using python sdk?

For example is there any API call to get data type of dimensions and metrics, ie 'CampaignId' or 'Impressions' from CampaignPerformanceReport?

Appreciate any help with this,

Cheers,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a set contract, so as a starting point please assume the data returned in the file is a string. You can assume the entity IDs e.g., keyword ID are long, and other columns will vary. Note, this is also answered in the [Bing Ads API Development forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/39b15a04-8a1b-408c-bf74-443d523d1ec1/how-to-get-data-types-for-requested-report-columns?forum=BingAds).